# How to prevent required validation on a read only form in .NET Core Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, razor, data-annotations

I have a read only form where it's only function is to search on the provided parameter and populate the form with the results, I am binding it to a model but the model uses the Required data annotation and when I click the search button, the ModelState.IsValid is false, when I checked to see which property it's complaining about, I found it's not even one I'm using on the form so because I also use this model for insert and updates and it has required properties, when I use it in a read only scenario, the form comes back invalid.  How can I stop the validation from occurring on the Required members in my model which aren't used on my form or supposed to be read only?

Answer (score 0):

If the form is for editing the record that has been searched, then I'd suspect that your model annotations apply.

If the form is not for editing, then it shouldn't be a form.  Just a collection of fields (that can still be bound to the model).  In this way the automated validations managed by the EditForm will not happen.

Or, if as you've discovered you're not using all of the properties of the model, then you should consider creating a view model (not an edit model) specific for the display of data in this view panel.

Comment: If I use extra view models based on a single model, would this mean I'd possibly have to create 2 or 3 models to deal with various scenarios?  For example, I have a member model which I need to use for read and update so I would need a read only model and an update model for member, but what if there was a 3rd scenario where I have a combination of read only properties and properties I need to update, in this case there are 3, would I need to create a model for those 3 as well?